# ¿Cómo obtengo los 5 últimos registros actualizados de una tabla cualquiera?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Si tengo una tabla como la siguiente, (ignorar las llaves foráneas):

```
CREATE TABLE public."CompromisoPag" (
    "iIdCompromiso" integer NOT NULL,
    "vCompromiso" character varying(800) NOT NULL,
    "iNumero" integer NOT NULL,
    "iEstatus" integer NOT NULL,
    "dPorcentajeAvance" numeric(5,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "iIdDependencia" integer NOT NULL,
    "vFeNotarial" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "vNombreCorto" character varying(500) NOT NULL,
    "dUltimaAct" timestamp without time zone,
    "vDescripcion" text NOT NULL,
    "iUltUsuarioAct" integer,
    "iIdTema" integer NOT NULL,
    "vAntes" text NOT NULL,
    "vDespues" text NOT NULL
);
```

y si en esa tabla tengo 20 registros y actualizo 5, ¿como obtengo esos registros actualizados? he estado leyendo que puedo obtener los 5 últimos registros insertados, pero en este caso no sé como recuperar los actualizados. En `dUltimaAct` tengo la última fecha de actualización.

Comment: `dUltimaAct` guarda la fecha de la última actualización?

Comment: si, en ese campo lo guardo

Comment: Ahi esta la solución, ordenas los registros por el campo **dUltimaAct** (`Order By`) y seleccionas los primeros 5 registros mediante `limit` (limit 5) o `fetch first` (fetch first 5 rows only)

Comment: si me funcionó, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Responderé para que aceptes la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar lo que necesitas, debes hacerlo mediante un **[ORDER BY](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-order-by/)**, **[LIMIT](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-limit/)** o **[FETCH FIRST](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-fetch/)** de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT * FROM CompromisoPag
ORDER BY dUltimaAct
LIMIT 5
```

También puedes utilizar fetch first en desmedro de limit

```
SELECT * FROM CompromisoPag
ORDER BY dUltimaAct
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

*Pero este sólo es válido desde la versión 8.4*

Comment: +1. No está de más aclarar que en caso de actualizar un conjunto grande de registros, y si todos comparten la misma fecha de actualización, lo que obtenemos es algunos de los 5 últimos registros, y no necesariamente siempre los mismos.

Comment: Buena acotación! Eso se solucionaría incluyendo, además de la fecha la hora, minutos y segundos si no me equivoco. Habría que analizar de que forma tiene el OP su campo :/